# Track all http request of $http, $resource in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, resources

I want to use Google Analytics for all of my requests. I am using $http and $resource and my application is too big, so I don't want to create any wrapper function. Is there way, in AngularJS 1.4.5, that I can track all requests and apply some Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [interceptor](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). By implementing the interceptor API and pushing it into the `$httpProvider`s interceptor array. If implemented properly, you can handle every request/response in a centralized manner.

Here's a sample using TypeScript and class syntax:

```
class ErrorInterceptor {

    static $inject = ['$q'];
    constructor(private $q: ng.IQService) {}

    public request = (config) => {
        // Do something on success
        return config;
    }

    public requestError = (rejection) => {
        // Do something on error
        return this.$q.reject(rejection);
    }

    public response = (response) => {
        // Do something on success
        return response;
    }

    public responseError = (responseFailure) => {
        // Do something on error
        // Handle error codes separately if needed, e.g.:

        if (responseFailure.status === -1) {

        } else if (responseFailure.status === 401) {

        } else if (responseFailure.status === 403) {

        } else if (responseFailure.status === 404) {

        } else if (responseFailure.status === 500) {

        } else if (responseFailure.status === 503) {

        } else {

        }

        return this.$q.reject(responseFailure);
    }
}

const ErrorInterceptorConfig = ['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider) => {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ErrorInterceptor');
}];

// Register the service and configuration:
angular.module('yourModule')
    .service('ErrorInterceptor', ErrorInterceptor)
    .config(ErrorInterceptorConfig);
```

As shown in the documentation linked above, you can also do this using an anonymous factory:

```
angular.module('yourModule')
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
            return {
                request: function(config) { ... },
                response: function(response) { ... },
                ...
            }
        }]);
    }]);
```